# Getting error: expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting the error in my last line of code (on the j variable). What could possibly be the issue? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(int *arr, int m, int n);

int main()
{
    int array[4][2], i, j;
    function((int*)array, 4, 2);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
            if (j == 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void function(int *arr, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j, element;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("Give element: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &element);
            arr[i][j] = element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler does not know the dimensions of `arr`. Try `void function(int arr[][2], int m, int n);` called with `function(array, 4, 2);` Also you ignore `m` and `n` and hard-code the loops. Alternatively you could *calculate* the index for a 1-D array.

Comment: `arr` is an `int *`; `arr[i]` is therefore an `int`; you can't subscript an `int`, but `arr[i][j]` tries to do so.  You need to work out how you want to pass a 2D array to your function.  Your cast in `main()` indicates some of the problem.  You should have `void function(int (*arr)[2], int m, int n)`, but you don't make use of `m` or `n`.  Or, if you have C99 and VLA support (unlikely since you're using `scanf_s()` and therefore probably using MS Visual Studio), you might use `void function(int m, int n, int arr[m][n])`.  You'll fix the 4 and 2 in the function to `m` and `n` too.

Comment: Replace `arr[i][j]` with `*(arr + 2*i + j)`. Also, `scanf_s()` is not part of the standard, try not to use it. Instead use `fgets` and parse with `strtol`.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar or even `*(arr + n * i + j)`